# Hibernate `unique` constraints not working if one of the multi-column constraint is null

Tags: hibernate, grails, constraints

There's a constraint in Hibernate called `unique` that makes a certain property throws an error if it is not unique when it validates. For example:

```
class Person {
    String id
    Person mother
    Person father
    String fullName

    // Mapping closure goes here

    static constraints = {
        father nullable: true
        fullName unique: ["mother", "father"]
        mother nullable: true
    }
}
```

In this scenario, any value of `fullName` is allowed as long as it's unique on every `mother` and `father` pair. So, if there is a record of a `Person`, let say, `id=03 fullName=Liam`, with mother `id=01 fullName=Olivia` and father `id=02 fullName=William`, there will be a validation error when another record with the same `fullName` `id=04 fullName=Liam` is inserted under the mother `id=01 fullName=Olivia` and father `id=02 fullName=William`. The validation works.

The problem is when one of multi-column unique constraint is `null`. For example, when a record `Person` `id=03 fullName=Liam` with mother `id=01 fullName=Olivia` and a `null` `father` is inserted and another record with the identical `fullName` and `mother` is inserted after, the validation will not trigger.

I want to know whether this a limitation.

P.S. I know that it is advised to have this unique constraint on the database side. I have that already. What I want is to have an equivalent checking on the Hibernate side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I currently using a custom validator to catch this (which beats the purpose of using the `unique` constraint).

```
fullName unique: ["mother", "father"], validator { val, obj ->
    withSession { session ->
        Long count = Person.createCriteria().get {
            projections {
                rowCount()
            }

            eq("mother", obj.mother)
            eq("father", obj.father)
            eq("fullName", obj.fullName)
            ne("id", obj.id)
        }
        if(count > 0) {
            return ["unique"]
        }
    }
}
```

And appended this line on `message.property` file:

```
person.fullName.unique=[{0}] with value {2} must be unique.
```